# My symfony code isn't considered

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

When i update my code , wamp always shows the older one,
and this problem also shows in routing beacuse i'm using symfony.
Even if i change routes i always get the error "no route found for get /newcourse"
This is part of the code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/newcourse")
     * @param Request $requ
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @internal param Request $req
     */
    public function addcourseAction(Request $requ)
    {

        $c= new Course();
        $form=$this->CreateFormBuilder($c)
            ->add("courseName",TextType::class)
//
}
```

I guess it is a problem with wamp cache and not the browser cache because i clear it often.
If it is the cache, how to clear it. If not, what do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has a caching system, too. Have you tried clearing the Symfony cache?

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html

Comment: I think the problem was cache as you said .I couldn't clear the cache even when executing the command.But when i created a new project where i used the same code it worked.

Comment: Caching mysteries can be rough. Sometimes it's quickest/easiest to start a fresh project and see what happens.

Upvotes for helpful answers are always appreciated. =}

Answer (score 0):

You have to "include" in your main routing file, the routes defined in your controller. All routes are loaded via a single configuration file - usually app/config/routing.yml. However, if you use routing annotations, you'll need to point the router to the controllers with the annotations. This can be done by "importing" directories into the routing configuration:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: I have already done that.The problem was Cache.Tha i couldn't clean even when using php bin/console cache:clear

Answer (score -1):

Routes in symfony should have names in them. Try declaring your route like this:

```
@Route("/newcourse",name="new_course")
```

Comment: "should have names" --- that's surely not true.

Comment: The attrubute "name" is optional . If not omitted it can be  used as a shortcut to your page within your code.